# php sort value ranges

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I have a array of strings:

0 - 5
50-100
10-50
150-250
100-150

Now I want to automatically sort these to:

0-5
10-50
50-100
100-150
150-250

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **[`natsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)** function. It sort numeric values "as a human being" :)

```
$input = array('0-5', '50-100', '10-50', '150-250', '100-150');
natsort($input);
print_r($input);
```

Answer (score 4):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php
Sort an array using a "natural order" algorithm

```
$a = array("0-5", "50-100", "10-50", "150-250", "100-150");
natsort($a);
print_r($a);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0-5
    [2] => 10-50
    [1] => 50-100
    [4] => 100-150
    [3] => 150-250
)
```

NOTE: the keys will stay the same and are not renumbered.

when this is not the desired result, you may want to renumber it yourself after the sort:

```
foreach ($a as $v)
    $new_a[] = $v;
$a = $new_a;
```

OR even better: (thx @liquorvicar)

```
$a = array_values( $a );
```

Comment: If you want to renumber the final array, it's easier just to call array_values() on it, i.e. $new_a = array_values( $a );